# How can I find text in class and class name having spaces through Beautiful Soup in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For example I have a class in a `<div>` and a class having spaces.

```
<div class="class name having spaces"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc ='''<div class='the value'><\div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml')

print(soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'the value'}))
print(soup.find_all(class_='the value'))
# if the part of value is uniqu, you can use them separately
print(soup.find_all(class_='the'))        
print(soup.find_all(class_='value'))
```

out:

```
[<div class="the value"></div>]
[<div class="the value"></div>]
[<div class="the value"></div>]
[<div class="the value"></div>]
```

Answer (score 2):

Having spaces means that the entry has two classes applied to it, e.g. `my` and `class` applied to it. If you are looking for all `<div>` entries containing those two classes then I suggest you use BeautifulSoup's [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) function as follow:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''
    <div class='my class'>test1</div>
    <div class='class my'>test2</div>
    <div class='my other class'>test3</div>
    <div class='my other'>test4</div>
    <div class='myclass'>test5</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.select('div.my.class'):
    print(div.text)
```

This will catch all places where both of the classes are present in the definition (and in any order). Giving you the following output:

```
test1
test2
test3
```