# Why can I scrape a table, but not a nested table?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

Hello I am trying to scrape some data from a sub-table (red arrow image) in wikipedia but it seems not working, returning me no data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_NBA_team_rosters').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
teams_table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'sortable jquery-tablesorter'})
```

However when i scrape the data from the actual table (green arrow image) it works fine.

```
teams_table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'toccolours'})
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you need to handle the whitespace character differently in `findAll`?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718366/beautifulsoup-and-class-with-spaces

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605305/how-can-i-find-text-in-class-and-class-name-having-spaces-through-beautifulsoup

Comment: `jquery-tablesorter` class name added dynamically. Try just `teams_table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'sortable'})`

Comment: @Andersson has the right solution. So give that a try and it should work.