# "SyntaxError: cannot assign to expression" and "SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal" for class name with spaces and numbers inside a div

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to make a web scraper for a website to let me know when an new item is available, but I encountered this problem in my code when trying to ask it to print me the URL:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://exchange.art/gson/nfts?sort=listed-oldest')
#r.status_code
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

resultado = soup.find('div', class_='h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1')
nftlink = []

for h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1 in resultado:
    for link in h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```

Line 16 shows:

> SyntaxError: cannot assign to expression

Line 17 shows:

> SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

I tried changing the long name of the class for "class_" so it could take the entire class name:

```
for class_ in resultado:
    for link in class_.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```

but it shows a new error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

What I'm trying to do with this code is using beautifulsoup to get everything from the page with r.content, then making a `soup.find` to get inside the `div`, the class that is called `"h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1"` exactly like that inside the elements. Now inside the `div` of the class, I want to the `"a"` which got the link I'm after, the `href`, then I did the `for` for the name of the class inside the variable of the soup.find and asking it for the link inside the class `name.find_all`.

But it shows those errors I think it's because of the name of the class, but not sure how to deal with it.

I'm using sublimetext 3 with python version  3.11.0

Comment: Are you trying to use `h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1` as a variable name? If so, why?

Comment: @user2357112 yeah I tried to use it as a variable name, but since I don't know much of python I'm not sure why it isn't working. I tried creating a variable with it inside like "class = h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1" and placing it in the for, but it didn't work :(. Since the class it's like that with spaces and - in the div code.

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is not a good way to explain what it is that you actually want. Neither we nor Python can guess what your ad-lib syntax is supposed to mean.

Comment: @tripleee hello I edited it with a better explain and added an image at the end. I hope it's clear enough, if not please let me know sir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605305/how-can-i-find-text-in-class-and-class-name-having-spaces-through-beautiful-soup#:~:text=2-,%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA

Comment: Is this work related? Are you new in your job?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus nope, just decided to do this for a community I'm in to try and help them, but since I'm new to python I'm still learning while I code this. I don't even have a job.

Comment: @СергейКох thanks for the link bro, checking it out.

Comment: I voted to reopen (@tripleee and others who closed it). Question was edited, code included, it deserves to be reopened imho. Once reopened, I will respond. It's not a difficult issue, the crux here is inspecting Network Tab, getting the API endpoint where the NFT data is pulled from, and modifying it a bit to get all of them in one call. You only need Requests and pandas to get a wealth of information about those NFTs.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Thanks man. I hope they reopen it so I can see your answer better and mark it as answered if possible. 
I see, I didn't know the website had to be searched in the network tab to get the API. I will check that out while they reopen it so I can figure this out hopefully. Thank you again.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Reopened now; thanks for the ping.

Comment: I don't know what you expect `for h-full aspect-h-16 aspect-w-16 ng-tns-c75-1 in resultado` to do. `resultado` is the return value from `soup.find`, so please look at the documentation what it returns. And you really should read the Python tutorial because this syntax doesn't make sense anyway and a "-" can not be part of the name of a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of obtaining the data - as a dataframe - and then you can scrape that endpoint at regular intervals, like every 3 hours - and compare the results with something like `first_df.compare(second_df)`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

url = 'https://api.exchange.art/v2/nfts/created?from=0&sort=contract-type&facetsType=collection&limit=300&profileId=TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['contractGroups'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
mint.isMasterEdition    mint.symbol mint.image  mint.offChainJsonMetadata.symbol    mint.offChainJsonMetadata.image mint.offChainJsonMetadata.name  mint.offChainJsonMetadata.description   mint.offChainJsonMetadata.files mint.offChainJsonMetadata.attributes    mint.masterEditionAccountPDA    mint.description    mint.collection.isDiscounted    mint.collection.isCertified mint.collection.isNsfw  mint.collection.description mint.collection.tertiaryCategory    mint.collection.bannerPath  mint.collection.tags    mint.collection.secondaryCategory   mint.collection.primaryCategory mint.collection.name    mint.collection.thumbnailPath   mint.collection.isOneOfOne  mint.collection.id  mint.collection.isCurated   mint.artistProfile.twitter.handle   mint.artistProfile.twitter.profileImage mint.artistProfile.assets.thumbnail mint.artistProfile.assets.banner    mint.artistProfile.md.displayName   mint.artistProfile.md.brandId   mint.artistProfile.md.creatorId mint.artistProfile.md.slug  mint.artistProfile.printServicesEnabled mint.market mint.masterEditionAccount.currentSupply mint.masterEditionAccount.maxSupply mint.name   mint.attributes mint.id mint.metadataAccount.mint   mint.metadataAccount.symbol mint.metadataAccount.isMutable  mint.metadataAccount.updateAuthority    mint.metadataAccount.creators   mint.metadataAccount.name   mint.metadataAccount.primarySaleHappened    mint.metadataAccount.sellerFeeBasisPoints   mint.metadataAccount.uri    mint.brand.name mint.brand.thumbnailPath    mint.brand.description  mint.brand.id   mint.brand.printServicesEnabled mint.brand.bannerPath   mint.masterEditionKey   mint.stats.highestOffer mint.stats.numListings  mint.stats.lowestListingPrice   mint.stats.numLiveAuctions  mint.stats.lastSalePrice    availableContracts.editionSales availableContracts.auctions availableContracts.listings availableContracts.offers
0   True        https://arweave.net/aib0aqUUIDrh1lHbIbvWRsfzeJmE6xObcK6u-b81TbE?ext=png     https://arweave.net/aib0aqUUIDrh1lHbIbvWRsfzeJmE6xObcK6u-b81TbE?ext=png La Marea    Artist digital painting \n*no ai\nPNG 9000px by 7200px\nat 300ppi\n\nI chose the title La Marea (Spanish for "the tide") as I wanted a link to Solana's history. \n\nSolana was named after a small beach town North of San Diego called Solana Beach, where Anatoly, Greg and Stephen lived and surfed for three years when they worked for Qualcomm. Solana is also Spanish for warm wind.\n\nI picked tide because it has a massive impact on surfing and while you're out in the waves you're constantly adapting to the changing conditions. There's also a phrase, "the tides of change" which I think captures nicely where we are in the transition from web2 to web3. The Solana blockchain is perfectly positioned to make the most of this.  [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/aib0aqUUIDrh1lHbIbvWRsfzeJmE6xObcK6u-b81TbE?ext=png'}]   []  BKHJAfu3hEWXV4uXGEhvc9EXpw3UPgVXwfRMUu2G4c3k    Artist digital painting \n*no ai\nPNG 9000px by 7200px\nat 300ppi\n\nI chose the title La Marea (Spanish for "the tide") as I wanted a link to Solana's history. \n\nSolana was named after a small beach town North of San Diego called Solana Beach, where Anatoly, Greg and Stephen lived and surfed for three years when they worked for Qualcomm. Solana is also Spanish for warm wind.\n\nI picked tide because it has a massive impact on surfing and while you're out in the waves you're constantly adapting to the changing conditions. There's also a phrase, "the tides of change" which I think captures nicely where we are in the transition from web2 to web3. The Solana blockchain is perfectly positioned to make the most of this.  False   True    False   Deconstruction becomes discovery, there is peace in discomfort and harmony where there is none. Glitch Art  non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/collections/GSON 2022/banner-4f110c8a-e8b9-422f-9472-eb084f3c7397.png   [GSON, abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, color, 2D]    Painting    Abstract    GSON 2022   non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/collections/GSON 2022/avatar-771d5605-507d-4420-8e64-fa9b76f9b56e.png   False   M65uOWo1YSmXkNKsPT96    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    primary 20  20  La Marea    []  5DFPjooRB2WHw6YcUkMeVKr19JmR9Skt5pCRcVeDTyDd    5DFPjooRB2WHw6YcUkMeVKr19JmR9Skt5pCRcVeDTyDd        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  La Marea    False   1000    https://arweave.net/I42BO-Nvxpj6efle3PaJp1ddtxaGs8wFEU-tIG5YyVU GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png BKHJAfu3hEWXV4uXGEhvc9EXpw3UPgVXwfRMUu2G4c3k    NaN 1.0 3.669000e+10    0.0 3.000000e+10    [{'data': {'editionsMintedSoFar': 20, 'preSaleWindow': 86400, 'price': 10000000000, 'initialPrice': 10000000000, 'saleType': 'LimitedEdition', 'start': 1664312400, 'blockTime': 1663913565, 'walletMintingCap': 1, 'version': 2, 'pricingType': 'Fixed'}, 'keys': {'mintKey': '5DFPjooRB2WHw6YcUkMeVKr19JmR9Skt5pCRcVeDTyDd', 'depositAccount': 'Tozd9mVPd8hXRFLaUGKxYW6St6VK3YmVxmfzmsXnjJz', 'saleAccount': '6zp3uHvSDvp1W4zurEfk8JpSzVMUZ1m68b8MdKNSnCsd', 'initializer': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV'}, 'type': 'editionSale'}]  []  []  []
1   True        https://arweave.net/6FZHV8h6U6T3i5KIR7rKBMQLDOiAuCVJQEQzlmkaWyI?ext=png     https://arweave.net/6FZHV8h6U6T3i5KIR7rKBMQLDOiAuCVJQEQzlmkaWyI?ext=png Mode One Collection – #82   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/6FZHV8h6U6T3i5KIR7rKBMQLDOiAuCVJQEQzlmkaWyI?ext=png'}]   []  AvC9ej7xxkLHqn1hNBm57JM98Sh48DuaYU1ujdu9N9rc    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #82   []  KiLXoAyao7tF52NZB9hauZxvjri6wFyeUSVgahC4SfE KiLXoAyao7tF52NZB9hauZxvjri6wFyeUSVgahC4SfE     True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #82   True    1000    https://arweave.net/bfeWalM4xiZ7OW0Ev5rEtrESzMFAmhFMGPP0CFYOCt0 GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png AvC9ej7xxkLHqn1hNBm57JM98Sh48DuaYU1ujdu9N9rc    NaN 1.0 3.900000e+09    0.0 2.000000e+09    []  []  [{'data': {'listingAmount': 3900000000, 'blockTime': 1668055220}, 'keys': {'escrowAccount': 'BTuWp3k9Qt4PV8iN4oioEe3LJG1qB9VTH9YfrCEynAVE', 'mintKey': 'KiLXoAyao7tF52NZB9hauZxvjri6wFyeUSVgahC4SfE', 'listedBy': 'BVEAy7LA81ANFK7zPhVf3iTDNNupNXYV6uDamN58fW9D', 'currentTempTokenAccount': 'stTukXZR7hMsw4F2NemvWJEsvVtooNjqFRaM8y5wBNN'}, 'type': 'listing'}]    []
2   True        https://arweave.net/--jCdhK_QNVwnVsH727x0IE0JpJvnUC6jO1ztF6Su2U?ext=png     https://arweave.net/--jCdhK_QNVwnVsH727x0IE0JpJvnUC6jO1ztF6Su2U?ext=png Mode One Collection – #25   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/--jCdhK_QNVwnVsH727x0IE0JpJvnUC6jO1ztF6Su2U?ext=png'}]   []  8S61pUhP7yUjXX9JgbhjboBs2wZ833TyKekPs1om52eJ    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #25   []  GsCs5vkWrdGK1jqyep2HthLmy3j3ccE8hQ9BPuowsNKQ    GsCs5vkWrdGK1jqyep2HthLmy3j3ccE8hQ9BPuowsNKQ        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #25   True    1000    https://arweave.net/R2zDO4snG1fowzT4kqIfuNLnNCgfa01OCpXZAeJo4cU GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png 8S61pUhP7yUjXX9JgbhjboBs2wZ833TyKekPs1om52eJ    NaN 1.0 4.000000e+09    0.0 2.000000e+09    []  []  [{'data': {'listingAmount': 4000000000, 'blockTime': 1668124822}, 'keys': {'escrowAccount': 'DjNA4F1d2iNdAtb2czcKMiKCHf9jjPRouHgHRQ9VdZhx', 'mintKey': 'GsCs5vkWrdGK1jqyep2HthLmy3j3ccE8hQ9BPuowsNKQ', 'listedBy': 'EpjrRsHiJVbWrxNQrD3GuskuiDrYSr1Ue1PCSR4yCVvb', 'currentTempTokenAccount': 'ENR62swkTi6n3K8dPNxYUkHBUBuDNmmP9zBT7juptbBV'}, 'type': 'listing'}]  []
3   True        https://arweave.net/Z4SVsy4uAaTGS5kn7qhP3REDt_VlKa3CCOWy7PveF9A?ext=png     https://arweave.net/Z4SVsy4uAaTGS5kn7qhP3REDt_VlKa3CCOWy7PveF9A?ext=png Mode One Collection – #28   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/Z4SVsy4uAaTGS5kn7qhP3REDt_VlKa3CCOWy7PveF9A?ext=png'}]   []  DtQqC7EZBn6aNYH3LnQFumjEKUceozEr2CZrYVB11pbK    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #28   []  HaiKgeAexGG24yCeynEGyoMpiWjLJaASCbA4KJaNKsJe    HaiKgeAexGG24yCeynEGyoMpiWjLJaASCbA4KJaNKsJe        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #28   True    1000    https://arweave.net/s0BbP8OyQ5aPfvblaVV796IE6IJ6C8U8u1-VpC7q-ak GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png DtQqC7EZBn6aNYH3LnQFumjEKUceozEr2CZrYVB11pbK    NaN 1.0 4.500000e+09    0.0 2.000000e+09    []  []  [{'data': {'listingAmount': 4500000000, 'blockTime': 1668124832}, 'keys': {'escrowAccount': '4mEj58cHDXcFMzYiGraZ2cH4brUWvaQpyMdMMZckg9Yu', 'mintKey': 'HaiKgeAexGG24yCeynEGyoMpiWjLJaASCbA4KJaNKsJe', 'listedBy': 'EpjrRsHiJVbWrxNQrD3GuskuiDrYSr1Ue1PCSR4yCVvb', 'currentTempTokenAccount': 'AjN2VnPf5Ltx6zj1wj1aTMESZkFwyK3dnU6roWDcJn9E'}, 'type': 'listing'}]  []
4   True        https://arweave.net/cKPd5CwqH-9FKdnzRF_eiPcau-odg_hDZ8sjZ_oxbbk?ext=png     https://arweave.net/cKPd5CwqH-9FKdnzRF_eiPcau-odg_hDZ8sjZ_oxbbk?ext=png Mode One Collection – #37   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/cKPd5CwqH-9FKdnzRF_eiPcau-odg_hDZ8sjZ_oxbbk?ext=png'}]   []  DyA9JgDJQwcdNfZKBNbJZca5fuMWuEmDhJHdmhhEBMDz    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #37   []  9Aej5jcoXBpzF6HSXM7GpQJRs5UQTG2jvaA6bCvMy3Ng    9Aej5jcoXBpzF6HSXM7GpQJRs5UQTG2jvaA6bCvMy3Ng        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #37   True    1000    https://arweave.net/zIAars8-F5vp2erWQxJbHSy-krGMC5AFBy_qFZapS_0 GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png DyA9JgDJQwcdNfZKBNbJZca5fuMWuEmDhJHdmhhEBMDz    NaN 1.0 5.000000e+09    0.0 2.000000e+09    []  []  [{'data': {'listingAmount': 5000000000, 'blockTime': 1668124837}, 'keys': {'escrowAccount': 'DJqNc2j4UoiqGKMR5BHrFhP3t942aAQ97kziKkEvJkHN', 'mintKey': '9Aej5jcoXBpzF6HSXM7GpQJRs5UQTG2jvaA6bCvMy3Ng', 'listedBy': 'EpjrRsHiJVbWrxNQrD3GuskuiDrYSr1Ue1PCSR4yCVvb', 'currentTempTokenAccount': '9D11YetKNdPNnhVa1NqkrNqa25ryL2PCzUeiK5xqwEh2'}, 'type': 'listing'}]  []
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
157 True        https://arweave.net/WalKgq-1EbaeagoV_qrdn7Jq1fdKH36Qw1LMFtDF0e8?ext=png     https://arweave.net/WalKgq-1EbaeagoV_qrdn7Jq1fdKH36Qw1LMFtDF0e8?ext=png Mode One Collection – #96   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/WalKgq-1EbaeagoV_qrdn7Jq1fdKH36Qw1LMFtDF0e8?ext=png'}]   []  EkNm8sjsLp3FbHEhWP3yj7bve8sRL75wgTRT4ZgZSoLd    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #96   []  B1QFGEFpFzWgxwGYtkHi5Sotxc8AN3kq6zc122aTFFrF    B1QFGEFpFzWgxwGYtkHi5Sotxc8AN3kq6zc122aTFFrF        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #96   True    1000    https://arweave.net/uH2IVnFCyBw5xkBk96I8ZqEBYxN813ge1ObeSft0eMo GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png EkNm8sjsLp3FbHEhWP3yj7bve8sRL75wgTRT4ZgZSoLd    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN []  []  []  []
158 True        https://arweave.net/jCVgednEe6VP1aQSm8uzVtBsNTvr0tQ5Jl7dTfwT6rM?ext=png     https://arweave.net/jCVgednEe6VP1aQSm8uzVtBsNTvr0tQ5Jl7dTfwT6rM?ext=png Mode One Collection – #98   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/jCVgednEe6VP1aQSm8uzVtBsNTvr0tQ5Jl7dTfwT6rM?ext=png'}]   []  GhZTGjGC4XDHTgPLZTA8pcmAPQ1BjL8Awz1Mu64Rb4N9    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #98   []  DSjLHnndFYqSJaYeasPsf1VwxKHD9PTmn5KPCzp61HM6    DSjLHnndFYqSJaYeasPsf1VwxKHD9PTmn5KPCzp61HM6        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #98   True    1000    https://arweave.net/Xcpuo3BJWNbsVRQ35EpHlIgy2w7-8klHo_Mx2lqEWi8 GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GhZTGjGC4XDHTgPLZTA8pcmAPQ1BjL8Awz1Mu64Rb4N9    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN []  []  []  []
159 True        https://arweave.net/RgZdrcC43xIEuCFg6PYsfyGnGCzFaFptQJHP5d4JrlU?ext=png     https://arweave.net/RgZdrcC43xIEuCFg6PYsfyGnGCzFaFptQJHP5d4JrlU?ext=png Mode One Collection – #99   1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/RgZdrcC43xIEuCFg6PYsfyGnGCzFaFptQJHP5d4JrlU?ext=png'}]   []  FtN5heg5yL9NUE9H88iSNsvuk42oZ6hb8dkQEK3Lzp3T    1 of 1, (from 150 image collection)\nArtist digital painting\n*no ai\nPNG 7500px by 6000px\nat 240ppi   False   False   False   Mode One Collection: Using generative art (or autonomous processes) to create a collection of abstract art. Made by hand, without any computer code.\n\n150 x 1/1 abstract art images   NaN non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/banner-356d9805-0a95-4a12-8198-3b378c33e6c2.png  [abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, colour, gson, generative art]   Painting    Abstract    Mode One Collection non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/series/Mode One Collection/avatar-61dd995f-b9e7-4b32-948c-c81fb4a6e63c.png  False   wNFjGxCngjvekRUEcjkY    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Mode One Collection – #99   []  6bySa1EdS1suRJFxTUba7CBKc8Cbp13Q3FfohTgQn39K    6bySa1EdS1suRJFxTUba7CBKc8Cbp13Q3FfohTgQn39K        True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Mode One Collection – #99   True    1000    https://arweave.net/OWHn5jFvZU77pe3sg2j0xPTn2PFKVAqOSz4PhYJsSo8 GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png FtN5heg5yL9NUE9H88iSNsvuk42oZ6hb8dkQEK3Lzp3T    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN []  []  []  []
160 True    GS22    https://arweave.net/irG4pUp6iq1OT63f1Lpxwvto5FZhG_Vy6QcVSxYp9uY?ext=png GS22    https://arweave.net/irG4pUp6iq1OT63f1Lpxwvto5FZhG_Vy6QcVSxYp9uY?ext=png Rapture 1 of 1\nDigital painting\nPNG 9000px by 7200px\nat 300ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/irG4pUp6iq1OT63f1Lpxwvto5FZhG_Vy6QcVSxYp9uY?ext=png'}]   []  CfaBcjS5jodLVfNeKk3BQKEyPJcBS56jeun9GtPtZ3qW    1 of 1\nDigital painting\nPNG 9000px by 7200px\nat 300ppi   False   True    False   Deconstruction becomes discovery, there is peace in discomfort and harmony where there is none. Glitch Art  non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/collections/GSON 2022/banner-4f110c8a-e8b9-422f-9472-eb084f3c7397.png   [GSON, abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, color, 2D]    Painting    Abstract    GSON 2022   non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/collections/GSON 2022/avatar-771d5605-507d-4420-8e64-fa9b76f9b56e.png   False   M65uOWo1YSmXkNKsPT96    False   None    None    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png GSON    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2    gson    True    secondary   0   0   Rapture []  2VT8AZBHv4v8raMNRQUjZUU3Y6eaVcsJAZxaGy3iMo9A    2VT8AZBHv4v8raMNRQUjZUU3Y6eaVcsJAZxaGy3iMo9A    GS22    True    69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV    [{'address': '69CvDtrERVArtBbPzQyaKjTxYUj6S2KGUpSTfcLjf2wV', 'verified': 1, 'share': 100}]  Rapture True    1000    https://arweave.net/Iht-z3KcbBNli-F7Ts4fZiSw_zIbcsiQ5hf32BkpsF8 GSON    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/avatar-2d37e18f-7088-41f9-9585-35a815108705.png Abstract digital artist.\n\nExploring the interaction of digital and analog mark making. Deconstruction becomes discovery. Read more about my process on my website.    6TPJMEaVZMlGrC5plUBJ    True    non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/banner-adaa6879-de15-4fac-a344-34be4c15817a.png CfaBcjS5jodLVfNeKk3BQKEyPJcBS56jeun9GtPtZ3qW    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN []  []  []  []
161 True    GS22    https://arweave.net/TTgUpEkhSul-26TFgNe7EHZBSlEjKJvRHUml9lPZxfA?ext=png GS22    https://arweave.net/TTgUpEkhSul-26TFgNe7EHZBSlEjKJvRHUml9lPZxfA?ext=png Vivify  1 of 1\nDigital painting\nPNG 9000px by 7200px\nat 300ppi   [{'type': 'image/png', 'uri': 'https://arweave.net/TTgUpEkhSul-26TFgNe7EHZBSlEjKJvRHUml9lPZxfA?ext=png'}]   []  8oj9oArMcsvYTc5AayLhu9pMeSHAX1WUvrCqqpzWARg 1 of 1\nDigital painting\nPNG 9000px by 7200px\nat 300ppi   False   True    False   Deconstruction becomes discovery, there is peace in discomfort and harmony where there is none. Glitch Art  non_live_data/creator_data/TZkdu8P94NQsvorpmrBQ46iP5wt2/brands/GSON/collections/GSON 2022/banner-4f110c8a-e8b9-422f-9472-eb084f3c7397.png   [GSON, abstract, abstract expressionism, digital abstract, digital painting, digital, painting, contemporary art, color, 2D]    Painting    Abstract    GSON 2022   

[...]
162 rows × 65 columns
```

Pandas documentation (to learn how you can implement compare, really straightforward) can be found at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html

For running the script at regular intervals, you can use `schedule`: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/
Take this as a learning opportunity, I'm sure you'll be fine. If you still cannot manage it, do tell and me (or someone else) will offer further help.

Comment: You are so kind, thank you so much for the help. With this information now I know where should I start looking and keep going with the code because I really wasn't expecting this. If maybe I get stuck at some point I will try and ask you (or someone else if possible). Thanks man, really appreciate it.